# Replacing a parameter in 2008 R2 SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008 R2 and report builder 3.0.  I have a cascading report issue that I need assistance with.  The first report runs fine.  Clicking on a link in the report passes a @processID parameter to the follow up report.

Now, when running the query with a string instead of the parameter directly in SSMS it takes under 1 second.  When I run it through SSRS with the parameter it takes about 15 minutes.  I've read that SSRS doesn't handle parameters very well.  What I would like to do is find a way to change the parameter into a string and then send that or if anyone knows of a better way.

Below is the query the report is running:

```
SELECT     ResultDetail_View.processOid, ResultDetail_View.applicationId, outputItem.outputValue, ResultDetail_View.startTime, ResultDetail_View.resultStatus, 
                      ResultDetail_View.statusMessage, ResultDetail_View.endTime, ResultDetail_View.ErrRec, COUNT(Summary.Id) AS SumRec

FROM         ResultDetail_View LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Summary ON ResultDetail_View.processOid = Summary.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      outputItem ON ResultDetail_View.outputOid = outputItem.outputItemOid

GROUP BY ResultDetail_View.processOid, ResultDetail_View.applicationId, outputItem.outputValue, ResultDetail_View.startTime, ResultDetail_View.resultStatus, 
                      ResultDetail_View.statusMessage, ResultDetail_View.endTime, ResultDetail_View.ErrRec

HAVING      (ResultDetail_View.processOid = @processID)

ORDER BY ResultDetail_View.startTime
```

Comment: How are you running your query in the report?  Is it a Stored Procedure?  If so, this looks a lot like [Parameter Sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) which will hamper SQL Server's ability to pick the best query plan.

Comment: Unfortunately these are inherited reports.  These are in an ad-hoc format and not in a stored procedure.  The code I posted is literally the dataset query that is run.  I have not found parameter sniffing on this yet.  I've done a recompile just in case and it still took the same time in both SSRS and SSMS.

Comment: Have you run a trace on the sql server instance to see exactly what query is being executed on the server when the report runs. Once you have that, if you run it directly in SSMS on the same server you should get the exact same performance (whether that be good or bad). It's not an answer but it should at least help you investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the original issue, it looks like you can change your `having` to a `where` without changing the query result?  If this is the case that will certainly help with performance.

Regarding the Parameter Sniffing, have you tried setting a local `nvarchar` variable and running the query this way in the report?

```
delcare @processIDLocal nvarchar(50) = @processID;

select r.processOid
      ,r.applicationId
      ,o.outputValue
      ,r.startTime
      ,r.resultStatus
      ,r.statusMessage
      ,r.endTime
      ,r.ErrRec
      ,count(s.Id) as SumRec
from ResultDetail_View as r
    left outer join Summary as s
        on r.processOid = s.Id
    left outer join outputItem as o
        on r.outputOid = o.outputItemOid
where r.processOid = @processID
group by r.processOid
        ,r.applicationId
        ,o.outputValue
        ,r.startTime
        ,r.resultStatus
        ,r.statusMessage
        ,r.endTime
        ,r.ErrRec
order by r.startTime;
```

Comment: This did not change anything with the time it was running. This is not a parameter sniffing issue as the same query run directly on SSMS runs in milliseconds.

Comment: @bwilliamson  "*as the same query run directly on SSMS runs in milliseconds*"  This is pretty much the biggest indicator of parameter sniffing...

Comment: If I run the same query in both locations with recompile, should it not pick the best plan for each?  Also if I change the dataset query in report builder to use just the string value instead of the @parameter, it runs in a second or two as well versus the 13 minutes.  The execution plan shows a difference between 1 row and 11 million rows through the process.

Comment: @bwilliamson Please read [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/).  You are literally describing parameter sniffing, you are just not doing the actually recommended things that help alleviate it like using local parameters.  The you are seeing a vast difference in the expected number of rows is what is causing the poor plan choice.